# How to write node js azure function logs in application insights?

Tags: node.js, logging, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to perform logging in node js azure function and logs should appear in application insights.

I tries using sdk and also have checked in application insights>live metrics >sample telemetry but custom logs which I have added with context.log() are not appearing anywhere not event inside application map.

So where else I can check for the logs? Can anyone please give me any example which I can refer to?

Comment: Can you show the code and relative setting files?

Comment: const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup(config.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY)
.setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
.setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
.setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
.start();
const client = appInsights.defaultClient;


Added this code above my function

Comment: inside the catch block I have added 
 client.trackException({exception: new Error(err), tagOverrides:operationIdOverride});

            context.log.error('Error===================>',err)

however I am unable to see the exception log when I am hitting the API from postman and looking into application insights>live metrics>sample telemetry

Answer (score 3):

You can [refer to the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#telemetryclient-api). There are many ways to do it.

[image]

Sample code in the offical document.

```
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup().start(); // assuming ikey in env var. start() can be omitted to 
disable any non-custom data
let client = appInsights.defaultClient;
client.trackEvent({name: "my custom event", properties: {customProperty: "custom 
property value"}});
client.trackException({exception: new Error("handled exceptions can be logged with this method")});
client.trackMetric({name: "custom metric", value: 3});
client.trackTrace({message: "trace message"});
client.trackDependency({target:"http://dbname", name:"select customers proc", 
data:"SELECT * FROM Customers", duration:231, resultCode:0, success: true, 
dependencyTypeName: "ZSQL"});
client.trackRequest({name:"GET /customers", url:"http://myserver/customers", duration:309, resultCode:200, success:true});

let http = require("http");
    http.createServer( (req, res) => {
    client.trackNodeHttpRequest({request: req, response: res}); // Place at the beginning of your request handler
});
```

Comment: Thank you Json, I will try to go with this implementation and will update you if it works for me.